# How to figure out why VS Code considers the certificate expired whereas it is not?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema, renovate

In VS Code, there is an error loading particular JSON schema (Renovate Bot).

`Unable to load schema from 'https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json': certificate has expired.(768)`

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "...": "..."
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

I've also tried associate the file with the schema via workspace settings, the same result.

Web server certificate seem to be valid:
[image: certificate]

Other schemas are loaded successfully, for example for `firebase.json` (set in workspace settings).

```json
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["firebase.json"],
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firebase/firebase-tools/master/schema/firebase-config.json"
    }
  ],
```

[image]

**How to figure out why VS Code considers the certificate stale whereas it is not?** I have not found any details on this in any of the Output panels.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bug reports for specific software should go to their owners, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh, I've just realized that the question is actually formulated as a bug report, not a question. I will try to rephrase it to fit into Q&A style. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Moreover, VS Code's GitHub [encourages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) to ask questions regarding the product [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code), that is why I did so. I'm not sure it's a bug, therefore just asking first how to figure out the reason of such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This has been annoying me for so long I can't remember.  However, it turns out I only encountered this issue when inside my company's network where there is a self-signed certificate between me and the internet.  On a whim I removed all of the expired self-signed certificates from "Manager Computer Certificates" and this error disappeared.

Therefore, for reasons I can't comprehend, VSCode (or whatever is actually running under the hood) is attempting to use expired system CA certificates and reporting an error as a result, despite a good certificate being present.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Though it may be useful to solve the issue, still this doesn't directly answer the question "How to figure out why VS Code considers the certificate stale whereas it is not?" Therefore I cannot accept this as an answer. Besides that, right now in VS Code 1.71.1 there is no such error for me, thus I cannot even assess whether this workaround works.